The range of symmetric 1D random walk
Let $p\in(0,1)$ be a constant, and $\{X_n\}_{n\ge 1}$ be independent Bernoulli trials with successful probability $p$. Define $S_n=2\sum_{i=1}^n X_i−n$, and $S_0=0.$
(1) The range $R_n$ of $S_0$,$S_1$,...,$S_n$ is defined as the number of distinct values taken by the sequence. Show that $\mathbb{P}(R_n=R_{n−1}+1)=\mathbb{P}(\forall 1\le i\le n,S_i\ne 0)$ as $n\to\infty$, and deduce that $n^{−1}E[Rn]→Pr(∀i≥1,Si≠0)$. Hence show that $n^{−1}E[Rn]→|2p−1|$ as n→∞.
(2) let p=1/2. Prove that E[|Sn|]=Θ(n).
As for (1),I think Rn=Rn−1+1 equal $S_n\neq S_1,S_n\neq S_2...S_n\neq S_{n-1}$,but that doesn't seem to be equivalent to $∀1≤i≤n,Si≠0$.And is $n->\infty,E[R_n]/n=1+\sum_{i=1}^\infty P({R_i=R_{i-1}+1)}/n=\frac{1+\Sigma_{i=1}^\infty P(∀1≤i≤k,Si≠0)}{n}->P(∀1≤i,Si≠0)$ correct? If it is correct, how can i arrive at $P(∀1≤i,Si≠0)=|2p-1|$
For (2), I know $\mathbb{E}[|S_n|]=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}n$,but to prove it is extremely troublesome since we only want to prove E[|Sn|]=Θ(n), is there an easier way?

Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.
